# Has to be of type Collison2D BUT my code is not about Collison

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This has nothing to do with collision so what do I do?
Unity error : This message parameter has to be of type: Collison 2D

```
IEnumerator bosstextgoaway()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(3f);
    BossText.text = "";
    BossText.GetComponent<Text>().enabled = false; //this is the line with the error
}
```

Comment: Where is the definition of BossText? is bossText a Text component from UI namespace? if is a Text why you call getcomponent if already is a Text?

Comment: Please provide more code (BossText class), otherwise it is impossible to tell where the error originates from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your BossText Variable is already a refernence to a Text Object. If it weren't you wouldn't be able to get the text of the Text Object.

But one line later you try to get the Text Object of a Text Object which doesn't work, instead you should just call .enabled on the Text Object already.

Example:

```cs
// Reference to the BossText Object.
[SerializeField] private Text BossText;

// Deactivate TextBox.
BossText.enabled = false;
```